# vuforia area target point clound

Tags: point, target, vuforia, point-cloud-library, area

i have a problem with area target.

Is there any chance to get point cloud or mesh from area target?

find point cloud from scanned area target

I'm waiting for any help. I use the vuforia area app for scanning.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the target from a capture you can ask to generate the authoring mesh. Generating a point-cloud is not possible. For more information see the documentation here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/area-targets/area-target-capture-api-unity